# How do I get SCUBA gear?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I am looking for a way to equip Scuba gear outside of a mission.

I know that you are automatically equipped with scuba gear when you exit the Submersible while in water.

1. Can anyone other than the owner of the Sonar Collections Dock enter the Submersible? If not, is there another one around?
2. Barring that, is there another way to get scuba gear?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was a Strangers and Freaks mission involving Michael and Abigail where you have to collect submarine parts for her underwater (the starting point of the mission is at the Sonar Collections Dock). Michael gets a Dinghy that is right next to the Submersible on the Sonar Collections Dock when he is on that Dinghy he can drive to those destinations and scuba dive inside the water to collect the submarine parts, basically you have to collect 30 of these parts to finish that Strangers and Freaks mission.

On collecting these submarine parts, I even found the part where Trevor sinks that weapons cargo plane from Merryweather underwater, and I found lots of weapons and ammo in that area.

I never tried going on the Dinghy after that mission, but I think you can still use that to scuba dive any time. Also, that mission to collect 30 submarine parts wasn't sequential; it was like collecting nuclear waste. You can resume it any time, as long as you kick those Strangers and Freaks missions on you can scuba dive anytime.

I went to the boatyard, and I was able to still find the Dinghy there, and was able to get the scuba gear as soon as I dived into the water from the Dinghy even after completing the Strangers and Freaks missions for Abigail.

[image: Map of described location]

<sup>[Image source](https://www.gamingreality.com/2013/09/gta-v-tips-hints-and-tricks.html)</sup>

Comment: You can also find that dinghy in freeroam, and you get the scubagear when you get out of the boat.

Comment: i was talking about the dinghy in the sonar dock, is that the one you're talking about?

Comment: Is there any other location where the Dinghy spawns regularly? Or do you have to start the Strangers and Freaks mission?

Comment: so far i have been going to the dock to get a dinghy but there are others. i will edit this post once i check my map again later.

Answer (score 3):

You automatically get one when getting out of a Dinghy or a submarine. I think this is working as well before/after the first missions introducing them.

Answer (score -4):

First you go to los santos air port and get a plane.
Then travel to the port of south Los Santos and go try and look for it. It might be underwater or not. Then when you found that go on your phone or tablet then download GTA V cheat code then when you downloaded it go on maps and go on maps submarine then go on number 12 then you get a submaian  and diving suit or what ever it is.

Answer (score -4):

I dived in the water there was a yellow boat and got on it hop off and I had a scuba suit