# Where can I get a new parachute?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I saw [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/136041/how-do-i-get-scuba-gear), which then sparked mine:  Outside of a mission/job, where can I get a new parachute?

Are the locations to getting a parachute different in online play vs single player?

I have had one in my inventory earlier, but I used it when I bailed out of a helicopter.  My character doesnt want to reuse the parachute after using it once....

Comment: I tagged both online and gta 5 because of my second question

Comment: I think I remember hearing (in game) that you can buy them from Ammu-Nation. Not sure though.

Comment: I think I remember an ingame tip saying you automatically get a parachute (for free) as soon as you enter a plane or helicopter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In single player the parachute unlocks in ammunation after you complete the mission [minor turbulence](http://gta.wikia.com/Minor_Turbulence).

In GTA Online the parachute (and the parachuting activity) unlocks at level 11. Then it becomes available for purchase at Ammunation.

You can also find parachutes around the map, such as on top of the FIB building. According to Gizmo3k you may pick these up and use them before unlocking them at level 11.
Another location is by the cargo ship on top of the loaders and on the large train bridge over the river leading to the Alamo Sea.
See [here](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/gta-v-online-list-of-what-unlocks-each-level.453418895/) for more detailed information about unlocks in GTA Online.

Comment: You can also get them when going in an plane/helicopter.

Comment: Only after doing the mentioned mission I believe

Comment: Mt. Chilliad is also filled with parachutes!

Answer (score 3):

I haven't played online yet but on the story mode/free roam after you play the mission where Trevor tails the Merryweather airplane and jumps out with a parachute. Parachutes becomes available in Ammunation. They should be on the left most aisle and its the second or third item from the top.

You will also get a text message for all the characters from Ammunation that parachute is available to buy after that mission.

Answer (score 1):

You can find one on mt. Chiliad next to a letter scrap in gta v story mode

Answer (score 0):

In GTA Online, you can find, wear and use parachutes before rank 11. I found one on top of the tall circular building in the middle of the city, just below the helipad. I also found one on the big green bridge overlooking the docks (near where Franklin snipes from if you do the dock heist).

I used it successfully last night, right before I hit rank 11.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you go into a plane that you've brought, and you've brought a parachute before then you get it for free. It works with me when I go in my Cuban 800.

Answer (score 0):

Also at the Vinewood sign' if you climb the "D" there's a parachute. Another I've found is on a bridge that can be easily found by going to the Los santos customs and following the train track on the left all the way to the bridge.